# Blazor Route Parameter as base

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Story: My plan is to use a Route Parameter to define which Tenant is selected on Client Side. I'm using [Blazor Server Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-server).

Problem: Now I'm define "/{TenantId}/X" in every Page.

Class:

```
public class Dashboard : ComponentBase
{

    [Parameter] public string TenantId { get; set; }

}
```

Page:

```
 @page "/{TenantId}/dashboard"
 @inherits DashboardBase

 <p>You have selected tenant: @TenantId</p>
```

Goal: My goal is to prevent to define it in every page and have it in a global way. So I can only type like that example code below:

Page:

```
 @page "/dashboard"
```

But I'm afraid it is impossible and BaseUrl can't really have a Route Parameter I guess. I have many creative ideas but I feel now I'm stuck cause my bad experience in Blazor.

Another question is that if I can use any middleware on client side or modify the the Router somehow?

Comment: Thought of a different domain/sub domain pointing to the same server for each tenant?

Comment: You have to define `[at]page "/xxx"` on every routed page, so what's seriously wrong about defining `[at]page "{TenantId}/xxx"`.  I can see the elegance in not having to, but...  Yes there are several ways to solve your problem, such as building your own router, but that's future maintainance for you when the current one gets changed (that happened between 3.1 and 5).  If you need the base code I can point you to a repo (I've been down this road before and backed out later).

Comment: There's a Repo here on Github - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/CEC.Blazor.RouteView and an article here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5299797/Adding-Dynamic-Routing-Layouts-and-RouteViews-to-t

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, ah cool! I think that is exactly what I'm looking for. I just need to understand the whole thing about router and your is a good example how to make it dynamic. I just need to adept it for my problem and hopefully it will work.